# Set comments in vim

Tags: vim

I am trying to make my comments to be of the following pattern:

```
/**
   Some comment    
*/
```

To do this, I put this line into my vimrc:

`set comments=sl:/**,mb:<Tab>,elx:*/`

But for some reason I still get the standard pattern of comments like in C.
If I leave mb: empty it gives a warning before opening or creating the file
as expected, so the option works.

Any ideas?

Adding a part of my vimrc to show indent options:

```
set number
set smartindent
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4 
set expandtab
set clipboard=unnamedplus 
set t_Co=256
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to expect too much from the `'comments'` option; Vim doesn't automatically insert or format comments (though this can be added via plugins). This option only affects the handling of comments as part of `'formatoptions'` (especially the `c` value, but also whether the comment leader is inserted on the `o` command).

By changing the start comment definition from the default `/*` to `/**`, you're only indicating that comments of the `/*` form are now treated as text, not comments (for formatting purposes, as governed by `'formatoptions'`).

The `mb:<Tab>` (does Vim show this as `<Tab>`; if you defined it right, it should come up as `^I`) just removes the default `*` comment leader; I think the indenting still is determined by your indent settings.

Comment: I added a part of my vimrc that might possibly contain any interfering indent options. Commenting them out does not change the way comments are formatted.

Comment: What do you type, and how do you format the comments? That would be interesting, too.